# Sendgrid - Error while updating card details and impossible to contact any Sendgrid support

Tags: sendgrid

When updating card details, I get the following error:

[ThreeDs2_Authentication_Exception] Transaction declined.402 - [card_error/card_declined/generic_decline] Your card was declined.

The card details are double checked and seem to be correct.
I tried opening a ticket on sendgrid or contact support via chat but apparently that functionality is broken on the official sendgrid site, so I'm trying my luck here.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist, this is something you need to take up with support as it can't be solved here on Stack Overflow. The ticket/chat system should not be broken (it seemed to be working for me just now) so please try again or follow the [alternative methods of using the support portal here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/support).

Comment: @philnash Thank you for your reply. I realize this ticket needs to be opened at Sendgrid support however, I've tried to open a ticket via the ticket/chat system and I get a message that the Ticket submission is down due to a server error. Also the "Chat with an agent" button isn't working. I tried multiple times in multiple browsers to no avail. Also no support email or phone number can be found. So coming here is kind of my last resort. Could you put me in contact with someone from Sendgrid?
[screenshot of error](https://imgur.com/a/IYe5wHx)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be down for me right now, are you able to raise a support ticket now?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the screenshot in my last comment I made just now. it's not working for me.

Comment: That's really odd, I can get to the form beyond that screen. Do you have any blockers in your browser that could be affecting the JavaScript?

Comment: That was one of my first thoughts too. I originally used Brave browser, so I put the shields down and tried again but no luck. Then I tried Edge which doesn't have any plugins, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you on a VPN of some sort? Or anything else affecting your connection?

Comment: I just tried with and without VPN and run into the same problem. Also tried on my mobile (via 4G) which also gives the same error message.

Comment: Sorry you're not able to use that form, I really don't know what's going on there. I'm trying to find another way for you to contact support without going through that form. I don't have a way myself to help with credit card issues, so I just need to get you in touch with support somehow.

Comment: OK, further update, if you can email me at philnash@twilio.com we will get a ticket set up in the system with your email address and start communicating that way. Sorry this is a hassle.

Comment: I understand. Thank you, I really appreciate your help. I was thinking about maybe calling the American sales phone number later today and see if they can help me. It's the only phone number I could find. +1 877 749 5740 (Monday - Friday, 9 am - 5 pm EST)

Comment: oh that's great. I'll do that right away. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**Try a different browser (like Chrome).**

This may or not be a solution, but it worked for me.

I'm on a Mac and couldn't add a SendGrid payment in Brave, but it worked when I switched to Chrome.

Likely it's due to some extensions I have installed, but this happens to me a few times a month on other websites.

Comment: This or a hard refresh on your browser. I tried adding a new CC and it told me it had failed and that I no longer had a payment method available. Tried adding again, but still failed. Hard refreshed the page and the payment information was there.